# Are Ear Files build once and Deploy on Multiple Apps server thing?

Tags: ear, weblogic9.x

Is it Possible to build a simple ear with just one "Hello World" html page to be build just once as ear file and deployed on weblogic, JBoss or any other server?

Means if Ear file is very simple which does not uses any advance services provided by specific container, is it possible this ear to be usable across different application servers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If the ear is J2EE compliant it should be able to be deployed to any J2EE compliant platform. If proprietary functionality like Websphere Scheduler is added then that would be different.